# Need to filter unique 10 countries

Tags: r

I have a dataset for number of bookings filtered for each hotel, and each country. For one country there are 2 rows because of 2 different hotels.
Ex:

```
Hotel    Country  Total

 A Hotel     PRT    1000
 B Hotel     PRT    500
 C Hotel     GBU    400
 D Hotel     TTT    350
 C Hotel     GBU    300
 E Hotel     GBU    300
 E Hotel     GBU    300
 F Hotel     GBU    300
 F Hotel     GBU    300
 G Hotel     GBU    300
 H Hotel     GBU    300
 I Hotel     GBU    300
 J Hotel     GBU    300
```

I need to find Total bookings for each hotel in the **top 10 countries** in a facet graph for each country. For top_n(10) it gives only 7 results in my grpah. How to find top 10 countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
## Find top 10 countries
data %>% group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(country_books = sum(Total)) %>%
  top_n(10, country_books) %>%
  ## Get the rest of the data for the top 10 countries
  inner_join(data) %>%
  group_by(Country, Hotel) %>%
  summarize(country_hotel_books = sum(Total))
```

Save that data set and use it for plotting.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code gave me exactly what I needed.